# Does boost::unordered_map return a reference or copy of value

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

When using a boost unordered_map, if I do map[key] will the type returned be a reference to the value V or a copy of the value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reference, otherwise this wouldn't work:

```
map[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html), it would appear to be a reference.

```
mapped_type& operator[](key_type const& k);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html)  :

> mapped_type& operator[](key_type const& k);
>
> **Effects:**
>   If the container does not already contain an elements with a key equivalent to k, inserts the value std::pair(k, mapped_type())
>
> **Returns:**
>   **A reference to x.second** where x is the element already in the container, or the newly inserted element with a key equivalent to k
>
> **Throws:**
>   If an exception is thrown by an operation other than a call to hasher the function has no effect.
>
> **Notes:** 
>   Can invalidate iterators, but only if the insert causes the load factor to be greater to or equal to the maximum load factor.
>
> Pointers and references to elements are never invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

The accessor operator `[]` always returns a reference. The map element will be created if it doesn't exist. So to avoid repeated searches, the following pattern is useful:

```
std::unordered_map<K, T> m = populate_me();

T & value = m[key];   // created if non-existent

// use "value" rather than repeated "m[key]"
```